# Child component not update value from Parent

Tags: vue.js

I am new vue js. I don't know why value in child component not update when I change value in parent component. Can anyone explain for me? I know that I can use `Times Updated: {{ times}}` to display. But I want to assign it into count to do something else

Parent
HTML

```
<div id="test">
  <button @click="clicktime">Click</button>
  <times-updated :times.sync="myData"></times-updated>
</div>
```

.js  file

```
var vm = new Vue({
  el: '#test',
  data(){
    return {
      myData: 100
    }
  },

  methods: {
    clicktime() {
      vm.myData = Math.random();
    }
  }
})
```

Child

```
Vue.component('times-updated', {
  props:["times"],
  data() {
    return {
      count: this.times
  }
},
  template: '<span>Times Updated: {{ count }}</span>',
});
```

link codepen: [enter link description here](https://codepen.io/nguyentrungmax/pen/XWWjrdQ)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `computed` data instead data element, which keep watch and updates

```js
Vue.component('times-updated', {
  props:["times"],
  computed: {
    count: function(){
       return this.times;
    }
  },
  template: '<span>Times Updated: {{count}}</span>',
});

var vm = new Vue({
  el: '#test',
  data(){
    return {
      myData: 100
    }
  },

  methods: {
    clicktime() {
      vm.myData = Math.random();
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.6.10/vue.js"></script>
<div id="test">
  <button @click="clicktime">Click</button>
  <times-updated :times.sync="myData"></times-updated>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the child you can use your prop value directly, then it'll work:

```
Vue.component('times-updated', {
  props:["times"],
  data() {
    return {
      count: this.times // not needed, not reactive
  }
},
  template: '<span>Times Updated: {{ this.times }}</span>',
});
```

Comment: As mentioned above because I need to use the variable count to do something else so I don't wanna use ```{{this.times}}``  to display/ Thanks for replying.

Comment: Ah i see, computed is the way to go then as stated above.