# How to wait for parent prop

Tags: vue.js

I have a parent component, on which I set a data property:

```
created() {
      carModels()
        .then(x => {
          this.carModels= [{ value: null, text: 'None' }].concat(x);
        });  
    },
```

`carModels` is a prop that is passed to child components. 
Currently, the prop is passed to the child before it is set in the above code. I have looked for a solution, but I am missing something...how do I wait for it, or, update the child once it has loaded? Presumably a `promise` would do this?

Comment: Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58429007/2815635)

Comment: @NikleshRaut is that how this is handled, computed? I am just wanting to wait for the async task in the code above to finish, so that `this.carModels` is populated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the direction in the comment from @Niklesh Raut, I resolved the issue using a watch in the child:

```
watch: {
      carModels: function (carModels) {
        console.log(carModels);
      }
    },
```